# How can i use expression interpolated expression in to a java script html

Tags: javascript, php, html, zend-framework

I have this(Works fine as a simple html):

```
{php}
        $this->assign("url", array('module' => 'Module', 'controller' => 'Controller', 'action' => 'edit'));
    {/php}

<a href="{$this->Url($url, 'default', true)}" class="content-load">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Back</button>
        </a>
```

But I want to use this in JavaScript (but i don't know how to make it work):

```
<script>
    html = ' <a href="{$this->Url($url, \'default\', true)}" class="content-load">\n' +
        '            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Back</button>\n' +
        '        </a>'
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You was converting that wrong.

```
var html = '<a href="{$this->Url($url, \'"default"\', true)}" class="content-load">'+
'\'        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Back</button>\' +\'+'+
'\'      </a>';
```

Comment: What is "fixed" and what is this `\' +\'+'+` ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to wrap a button in a link

```
html = '<a href="{$this->Url($url, 'default', true)}" class="content-load btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Back</a>'
```

should work too